# What constitutes a draw?

Tags: rules, endgame, fide, draw, stalemate

I know what makes a game a stalemate, and I know that stalemate is 1/2 point to everyone, and I assume draw is the same, but can there be a draw without a stalemate?

Comment: The definitive answer is Article 9 "The Drawn Game" in https://www.fide.com/FIDE/handbook/LawsOfChess.pdf , but for a beginner some explanation of what is being said there is probably required

Answer (score 6):

As Ian Bush points out in his comment the gory details are spelled out in the latest version of [FIDE Laws of Chess](https://handbook.fide.com/chapter/E012018). Article 9 covers most of the points but others are hidden in articles 6.9, 7.5.5 and A.4.3

Summarising:

1. Players agree a draw
2. Stalemate
3. Neither player can mate the other even with the other player trying to get checkmated
4. Correct claim by the player on move that the position has or is about to be repeated for the 3rd time
5. Correct claim by the player on move that 50 moves (100 half moves) have been completed or are about to be completed with no captures or pawn moves
6. Variation of 4. If the position is repeated 5 times then regardless of any claim the game is drawn. An observant arbiter is supposed to spot this and step in.
7. Same variation of 5. If 75 moves (150 half moves) have been completed with no pawn moves or captures then the game is drawn.
8. If one player "loses" for a "normal" chess reason (doesn't include resigns) but the opponent can't mate with any series of helpful moves from both sides (i.e. helpmate is impossible) then the game is drawn. These "loses" include losing on time, two illegal moves.